# View of the one fragment displaying behind another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I have multiple fragments in my app,ok lets say i have fragment f1 and f2..now in f1 i have imageview and buttons,now if click on button it goes to f2 and display f2,but in background the view of the f1 is still visible,can any one tell what is the issue with fragments in my app,thanks in advance

Fragment 1 button's listener

Shopfragment is second Fragment

```
hp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShopFragment tf = new ShopFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                tf.setArguments(bundle);
                android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container_body, tf);
                ft.setTransition(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();

            }
        });
```

Comment: You need to replace the fragments rather than just adding fragment 2. So fragment 1 is removed.

Comment: I answered in the answers, let me know if it worked.

Comment: @Aditya you can post the code of placing first fragment in view

Comment: the code of first fragment's butoon click is in question

Comment: @Aditya how you place the first fragment in view

Comment: @Aditya why am asking this is i found the solution.But i want to confirm it where it happens because of it or not...

Comment: Yeah, would be great if you showed how you place the first fragment.

Comment: i have tabhost with two frags..discover and shop..in both layout i put one footer..in that fotter i have same buttons..like in discover footer buttons with disc and shop and also in shop frag same buttons..now user can go to any fragment any time

Answer (score 0):

Replace it rather than adding it. Something like the following:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
FragmentTwo f2 = new FragmentTwo();
ft.replace(R.id.container, f2);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: I need to go now, I'll be back in a couple of hours and I'll try to help you if you haven't got this solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used the two fragment with 2 FrameLayout container, so you  replaced the second fragment, the first fragment is not replaced and it's also visible. Check the layout again!

Comment: i have single framelayout

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove old fragment from background:

```
ShopFragment tf = new ShopFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
tf.setArguments(bundle);
android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container_body, tf);
                ft.setTransition(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

//oldFragment -> reference to old fragment
if(oldFragment != null){
    ft.remove(oldFragment);
}
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: what is oldfragment here

Comment: Earlier fragment that was in the container.

Answer (score 0):

adding a fragment to backstack would cause the old fragment instance not to be destroyed. It's for handling back button clicks by android system to bringing user to old fragment by reversing the transaction.

In your case you should perform your removal operation in another transaction. So that android will not keep the info of this transaction. I should remind that hitting the back button on ft2 will give you activity without a fragment.

```
    ShopFragment tf = new ShopFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    tf.setArguments(bundle);
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ftRemove.remove(oldFragmentInstance);
    ftRemove.commit();

    android.app.FragmentTransaction ftAdd = fm.beginTransaction();
    ftAdd.setTransition(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ftAdd.add(R.id.container_body, tf);
    ftAdd.addToBackStack(null);
    ftAdd.commit();
```

would fix your problem hopefully

Comment: .remove cannot be applied

Comment: now click event is not working..i mean nothin is happening on click event

Comment: i have edited, there is a new instance named oldFragmentInstance. You should obtain instance of the fragment to be removed using either getFragmentManager().findFragmentById() or getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag() methods. Putting "this" as oldFragmentInstance parameter would work if you are inside of the fragment

Comment: my app got vanished..:( java.lang.ClassCastException: info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.DiscoverFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: I don't know the reason you are using android.app.Fragment but i could highly recommend using android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87648/discussion-between-aditya-and-deliganli).

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure whether you used

> android.support.v4.app.Fragment

for first Fragment placement.If you done like that then the problem is with this one.
when you try to place the Fragment with different support version you will receive the problem.

(i.e)if you place

> android.app.Fragment

support version fragment above the

> android.support.v4.app.fragment

support version fragment.you will get the android.app.Fragment support version fragment as transparent.

In order to solve this problem use same support version fragment.

**INFO ABOUT TWO SUPPORT VERSIONS**

**android.support.v4.app.Fragment**

android.support.v4.app.Fragment is the Fragment class in the android support library, which is a compatibility package that allows you to use some of the newer features of Android on older versions of Android.

**android.app.Fragment**

android.app.Fragment is the Fragment class in the native version of the Android SDK. It was introduced in Android 3 (API 11).

If you want to make your app use fragments, and want to target devices before API 11, you must use android.support.v4.app.Fragment. However, if you're only targeting devices running API 11 or above, you can use android.app.Fragment.